# How to map json item value to sibling array with jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq, flatten

Having json like

```
[
  {
    "parent": "x",
    "children": ["a", "b"]
  },
  {
    "parent": "y",
    "children": ["c", "d", "e"]
  }
]
```

how to transform it with jq to the array of "[parent, child_order_number, child]" items like

```
[
  ["x", 0, "a"],
  ["x", 1, "b"],
  ["y", 0, "c"],
  ["y", 1, "d"],
  ["y", 2, "e"]
]
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq -c '[.[] | range(.children|length) as $i | [.parent, $i, .children[$i]]]' file
```

yields:

```
[["x",0,"a"],["x",1,"b"],["y",0,"c"],["y",1,"d"],["y",2,"e"]]
```